# Ultisnips: option to disable some snips with a single ex command?

Tags: python, vim, ultisnips

I'm writing Latex, and recently found some of the following snippets:

```
snippet // "Fraction" iA
\\frac{$1}{$2}$0
endsnippet

snippet '((\d+)|(\d*)(\\)?([A-Za-z]+)((\^|_)(\{\d+\}|\d))*)/' "Fraction" wrA
\\frac{`!p snip.rv = match.group(1)`}{$1}$0
endsnippet

priority 1000
snippet '^.*\)/' "() Fraction" wrA
`!p
stripped = match.string[:-1]
depth = 0
i = len(stripped) - 1
while True:
    if stripped[i] == ')': depth += 1
    if stripped[i] == '(': depth -= 1
    if depth == 0: break;
    i -= 1
snip.rv = stripped[0:i] + "\\frac{" + stripped[i+1:-1] + "}"
`{$1}$0
endsnippet

snippet / "Fraction" iA
\\frac{${VISUAL}}{$1}$0
endsnippet
```

For my logic class, we use the notation v(u/y) to denote something, but I don't want the u/y to actually become a fraction. Usually what I do is comment out these snippets for the time being, and for my probability class, when I actually do want fractions, uncomment them.

Clearly this is a travesty of the utility of Ultisnips. How can I make my life easier by, for example, just issuing a simple ex command to comment these things out (without commenting out the rest of my tex.snippets)? Is there any other way to make my life easier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the format is always like the examples, you could use tpope/commentary to do

```
:g/Fraction/norm gcap
```

Otherwise you’ll need to find the appropriate range in the file and do

```
:[range]s/^/"/
```

---

Is it possible to use `v(u|y)` instead in your logic class, avoiding the snippets altogether? Alternatively, disable automatic firing of the snippets when working on those files (I thought Ultisnips required a trigger anyway.)

Comment: Yes! I forgot that there was an option to control autofiring (this is the `A` at the end of lines like `snippet // "Fraction" iA`) since I copied and pasted this code from https://castel.dev/, but just removing them worked!